# How to decide what variables to weight in a WLS regression

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, weighted-regression

My question concerns the weighting procedure used when using weighted least squares and multiple variables. I'll start by explaining my own limited understanding of how to conduct a weighted regression, and then get to my actual questions.

Step 1: Test variables for heteroscedasticity. For regressions, I tend to use the R function `bptest` for the Breusch-Pagan test like so:

```
bptest(y ~ x1, data = dat)
```

Step 2: A significant result (p < 0.05) indicates that variance scales with x1, and use of WLS is justified. Construct a linear model, and use the residuals from that model to make your weights, like so:

```
lm1 = lm(y ~ x1, dat)
w = lm1$residuals
w = 1/abs(w)
```

Step 3: Conduct the WLS:

```
lm2 = lm(y ~ x1, dat, weights = w)
summary(lm2) #oooh and ahhh at your results
```

Hopefully everything above is generally correct, again, I am learning.

Where I am now confused applies to Steps 1 and 2. For step 1, I could reasonably see proceeding with a multiple regression in two ways.

```
bptest(y ~ x1, data = dat)
bptest(y ~ x2, data = dat)
bptest(y ~ x3, data = dat)
## OR
bptest(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = dat)
```

**Question 1**: Now at step 2, I don't know whether only the variables detected to be significant by bptest or all of the variables of interest should be included in the linear model that I calculate `w` from *OR* if I should be using the bptest result that included all variables to inform my decision to use WLS.

**Question 2**: In a slightly more complicated scenario, would if affect your decision if a variable was detected as significant by itself, but the more inclusive model including all three variables was not significant?

For example in a scenario where only x1 was significant:

```
lm1 = lm(y ~ x1, dat)
w = lm1$residuals
w = 1/abs(w)
## OR
lm1 = lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, dat)
w = lm1$residuals
w = 1/abs(w)
## Either option followed by:
lm2 = lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, dat, weights = w)
```

**Question 3**: I could reasonably see either option being correct, but I am curious if there is a consensus view on which version is more correct. My only concrete thoughts are that I shouldn't choose how to carry out this method by seeing which one gives me the most favorable result, and that I should specify exactly how I did this procedure in future writeups.

I'm sorry if there is already a post somewhere discussing this, but I could not find any discussing this particular gap in my knowledge and none of the few books I have seem to have any relevant guidance.